# PHP Looping through each item on a one dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

If I have array like this myarray[0]['field1','field2','field3'];

I know its basically one row and has nothing to loop through, but i need it to loop through the values rather than the whole array.  In this case it would need to loop 3x but if there were 10 fields, it should loop 10x.

I've been doing this but it feels too complicated for something so simple.  Is there a function that is eluding me on google for this?

```
foreach (myarray[0][field1] as $item){
 //do something
}
foreach (myarray[0][field2] as $item){
 //do something
}
foreach (myarray[0][field3] as $item){
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Use nested loop

Comment: You could count the fields and create a for() loop with the outcome.

Comment: Can you show us what result you're expecting? The question is very unclear.

Comment: Ya, I dont want to do the counting approach.  I was hoping there is a clean function thats role is to loop the values rather than the whole array index.

Comment: You need to show us the expected result so we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does `myarray[1]` exist? It looks like you are trying to loop through a result set from a database query or some other datasource such as JSON.

Comment: Well the code above works, its just redundant and looks like the type of thing there would be a function for.  I'm not looking for any screen output, so theres nothing to show.  I know there are many ways to take counts, and write extra logic, just thought maybe I was missing a function that iterated through values rather than the whole array index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 2-dimensional array, but you want to only consider the second dimension? So treat the first dimension as a variable:

```
foreach ($myarray[0] as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

If you want to know the field name and value, then:

```
foreach ($myarray[0] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew something easy was eluding me.

Answer (score 3):

Use nested loops:

```
foreach ($myarray[0] as $field => $field_array){
    foreach ($myarray[0][$field] as $item) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The user updated the question. It should be enough with just the outer loop since `field1` etc seem to be values, not keys. I'm not sure though. The question is pretty unclear.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson question is very much unclear now! :-|

Comment: This will work, and it may be the only way.. I thought perhaps there was a way to do something like *pseudocode* foreach(*value in this array index*) but if something that simple doesnt exist I can go nested.

Comment: @weekapaug if it works for you, you may consider accepting it :)

Comment: @weekapaug additionally, if you have different "do something" for every key inside the array, you may consider [Strategy Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm)

Comment: your code has typo, that is why it can not work for OP :-) `myarray` should be `$myarray` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($myarray[0] as $field => $field_array){
    foreach ($field_array as $item) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: it does work, there were alot of similar correct answers. thanks!